# ExtraTreesClassifier with sparse training data?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am trying to use an `ExtraTreesClassifier` with sparse data, as per [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.ExtraTreesClassifier.fit), however I do get a run time `TypeError` asking for dense data. This is on scikit-learn 0.17.1, and below I am quoting from the documentation:

`Parameters: 
X : array-like or sparse matrix of shape = [n_samples, n_features]`

The code is quite simple:

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix, csr_matrix, hstack
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
import numpy as np
from scipy import *

features = array([[1, 0], [0, 1], [3, 4]])
sparse_features = csr_matrix(features)
labels = array([0, 1, 0])

classifier = ExtraTreesClassifier()
classifier.fit(sparse_features, labels)
```

And here the exception: `TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.`. This works fine when passing in `features`.

Looks like the documentation is out of date or is there something wrong with the above code?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: In documentation: "a sparse matrix is provided to a sparse csc_matrix", try with csc_matrix.

Comment: Also, I have run your code on sklearn == 0.17.1 and it works normally (both with csc and csr matricex).

Comment: Thank you, I have tried using the csc_matrix and it does indeed work. I apologize, my understanding of the docs was that X is internally converted to that format if it's a sparse matrix. Please do add your input as an answer and I'll close the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the documentation:

> Internally, it will be converted to dtype=np.float32 and if a sparse matrix is provided to a sparse csc_matrix.

So I expect that passing a `csc_matrix` should help.

On my setup both version work normally (csc and csr, sklearn 0.17.1), I assume that problems could be with older versions of scipy.